# Catch click on balloon tray icon

Tags: c, system-tray

How to catch click on balloon tray icon?
What message it sends to window?
Scenario:
 The application shows balloon and user clicks on some point in the balloon space or to close button on balloon form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you get sent is always the one you passed to Shell_NotifyIcon. The lParam of the message will be NIN_BALLOONUSERCLICK. You don't get to find out whether the user clicks the close button or not.